# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'supportsWebRTC' of undefined

Tags: javascript, opentok

I am working with **OpenTok Javascript API**. I have created sessionId and token from **https://dashboard.tokbox.com/keys**. I have made 2 connections using the same sessionId but 2 different tokens. The session is connected and I have checked it in ***session.on({sessionConnected: function(event){console.log(event.target.connections.length());}})***. I got 2 connections now. But when I try to connect using other connectionId with the code ***OT.Connection(connectionId, creationTime, data)***, I got this error ***"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'supportsWebRTC' of undefined"***. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: "But when I try to connect using other connectionId with the code OT.Connection(connectionId, creationTime, data)" What are you trying to do? You're already connected, there is no reason to create another connection, and OT.Connection() is not part of the public API, so its not meant to be called directly.

Comment: but how can I send signal to the other connection? In the following code, we have connection right? 'session.signal({type: "foo",to: connection,data: "hi..."}, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("signal error ("
                             + error.code
                             + "): " + error.message);
            } else {
                console.log("signal sent.");
            }
        });' How can I make the "to" connection? Without establishing connection using OT.Connection(), is there a way to establish "to" connection?